# Page shows code not rendering

Tags: html

[image]I know this is simple question, but i am fighting with it for few hrs, so its better to ask in forum to get help quickly. I have added the following simple html snippet in a TextEdit program and saved the file as webpage(.html). When I run this file in any browser, like safari, chrome or firefox, it shows the same code there instead of rendering this as web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me to show this as real web page rather than source code showing?

Comment: are you sure it's saving as `.html`?

Comment: I am saving it as webpage(.html).

Comment: Just tried with Firefox 26.0. Works fine. I second @jmore009's suggestion - make sure it is being saved as `.html`, and that TextEdit isn't putting a hidden `.txt` or something on the end

Comment: in your text editor you may have to choose to save it as an html document and not just add .html to the end of the file

Comment: No..I put extension as .html and verified, it shows as .html document only.

Comment: Perhaps TextEdit is putting formatting in? It looks like a formatted text editor - right click in your web browser with the page 'open' and view the source to check.

Comment: Can you post a link to this online?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>It is likely that</s> TextEdit **has** formatted your text, since by saving it as a Web Document it thinks that you have typed up the web page how you want it displayed, with all formatting, instead of raw HTML code. Try to save the document as raw text, then change the extension manually from whatever it is (probably `.txt`) to `.html`. For a more permanent solution, it is advisable to use a non-formatting text editor when coding.

EDIT: This is what Apple have to say: http://support.apple.com/kb/ta20406

Comment: I added a screenshot above, where its showing the output as code and view source of that page.

Comment: Well. As you said, i saved as rich text format, and then manually renamed the extension as .html, and its showing now this as web page.

Comment: Shall I use some other editor for creating html page instead of TextEdit?

Comment: TextEdit – with the right settings – is perfectly fine for the start.

Answer (score 13):

If you have access to the server scripts creating the page, then check if somewhere the http headers are being changed by that code. The browser needs to receive a header like that

```
Content-Type: text/html
[example in PHP: header(Content-Type: text/html);]
```

in order to render html properly. If this header is changed, then the browser won't be able to interpret it as html.

Comment: I found an old .htaccess file in the parent folder that was causing my HTML to be rendered this way.  Renaming/reworking the .htaccess file or just moving the HTML to another folder fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to your problem is simple.
Just open TextEdit and go to preferences.
Just tick the box which says"display html files as html code instead of formatted text".
Your problem will be solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

In case any of you have already created the file and not sure how to proceed, open the file in TextEdit. Go to Format -> Make plan text. Then save and close the file. Then open the file location in finder and rename to .html and this will convert the file appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the text you pasted in as HTML **content**, in the HTML editor. Instead, you should try to paste the text in the **code** view, not the **editor** view.