# How do I link to an external HTML files in Javadoc and have it appear formatted correctly?

Tags: javadoc

I looked at this portion of the Javadoc documentation, which says you can include HTML files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#unprocessed

I placed an HTML file in my doc-files directory, but a link () to it shows up as HTML code. How do I get the Javadoc compiler to render it in the final output?

I know how to include images. I also have included an overview.html file, so I know how to do that, but this file should appear elsewhere in the Javadoc. I have some long tables that would clutter the main documentation and should be reference doc only.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it can be done with JavaScript? I tried it but it didn't work for me -- maybe I did it incorrectly.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=228608
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of creating the HTML file in TextEdit instead of another editor, like Xcode:
[Page shows code not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066660/page-shows-code-not-rendering)
https://support.apple.com/kb/ta20406?locale=en_US

That was the entire problem.