# HTML displayed as text

Tags: php, html

I have a **.php** file which contains html code. The issue I am having is that it's being displayed as text, not as html elements. I have found several other questions regarding the same problem:

[Why is this HTML showing up as plain text in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107855/why-is-this-html-showing-up-as-plain-text-in-browser)

[Browser shows plain text instead of HTML in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439513/browser-shows-plain-text-instead-of-html-in-mac)

[Page shows code not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066660/page-shows-code-not-rendering)

However, I believe that everything the people suggested there applies to my code.

My code:

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// files needed to connect to database
include_once '../config/database.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();

$error = "";
if (isset($_GET["key"]) && isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["action"]) && ($_GET["action"]=="reset") && !isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $key = $_GET["key"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM password_reset_temp WHERE email=:email AND `key`=:key";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":key", $key);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => $e->getMessage()));
    }
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        $error .= '<h2>Invalid Link</h2>
        <p>The link is invalid/expired. Either you did not copy the correct link
        from the email, or you have already used the key in which case it is 
        deactivated.</p>
        <p><a href="...">
        Click here</a> to reset password.</p>';
    } else {
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $expDate = $row['expDate'];
        if ($expDate >= $curDate){
// the part that is not showing begins here                
?>
            <br />
            <form method="post" action="" name="update">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <br /><br />
            <label><strong>Enter New Password:</strong></label><br />
            <input type="password" name="pass1" maxlength="15" required />
            <br /><br />
            <label><strong>Re-Enter New Password:</strong></label><br />
            <input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="15" required/>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
            $error .= "<h2>Link Expired</h2>
            <p>The link is expired. You are trying to use the expired link which 
            as valid only 24 hours (1 days after request).<br /><br /></p>";
        }
    }
    if($error!=""){
        echo "<div class='error'>".$error."</div><br />";
    } 
} // isset email key validate end


if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["action"]) &&
 ($_POST["action"]=="update")){
$error="";
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["pass1"]);
$pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["pass2"]);
$email = $_POST["email"];
$curDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if ($pass1!=$pass2){
$error.= "<p>Password do not match, both password should be same.<br /><br /></p>";
  }
  if($error!=""){
echo "<div class='error'>".$error."</div><br />";
}else{
$pass1 = md5($pass1);
mysqli_query($con,
"UPDATE `users` SET `password`='".$pass1."', `trn_date`='".$curDate."' 
WHERE `email`='".$email."';"
);

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `password_reset_temp` WHERE `email`='".$email."';");

echo '<div class="error"><p>Congratulations! Your password has been updated successfully.</p>
<p><a href="...">
Click here</a> to Login.</p></div><br />';
   } 
}
?>
```

My .htaccess looks like this

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

The output:

```
<br />
            <form method="post" action="" name="update">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <br /><br />
            <label><strong>Enter New Password:</strong></label><br />
            <input type="password" name="pass1" maxlength="15" required />
            <br /><br />
            <label><strong>Re-Enter New Password:</strong></label><br />
            <input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="15" required/>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="..."/>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
            </form>
```

All the other **.php** files in that directory work perfectly. If you need any other information, let me know.

Comment: Is this embedded inside another file? If not, you're missing the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, at a minimum.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless. (And if you are going to put a `<string>` inside very label, you should probably use `font-weight` on them instead)

Comment: Multiple `<br>` elements are not a good substitute for CSS margins.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: @Quentin Im using prepared statements, is that not enough?

Comment: @php_n00b — You aren't at the bottom.

Comment: @Quentin the second part will be rewritten, since its from a tutorial. Im usually using Bcrypt. The question was about the first part, where I was stuck. I included the bottom unchanged code in case it was relevant. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
> ```

You said it was JSON and not HTML.

The browser is trying to treat it as JSON, failing, and showing it as text instead.

Comment: That was indeed causing the error, changing it from "application/json" to "html" worked for me! Thanks

Comment: "html" is not a valid content-type. It should be `text/html`, but that's the default for PHP so remove it entirely.